# image uploading trouble in django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

i have uploaded image but it is not showing up in page.
Uploaded image is also not showing up in media folder.
Used django forms for uploading image.
have a look at my code snippets:

my `models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    blog_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)
    @property
    def img(self):
        if self.blog_img and hasattr(self.blog_img, 'url'):
            return self.blog_img.url
        else:
            return "#"
```

my `views.py`:

```
 def post_new(request):
     if request.method =="POST":
         form = PostForm(request.POST , request.FILES)
         if form.is_valid():
             post = form.save(commit=False)
             post.author= request.user
             post.save()
             return redirect('post_detail',pk=post.pk)
         else:
             form=PostForm()
         return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html',{'form':form})



def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

i have added this in settings.py:

```
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

my post_list.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
   <div class="h2">
   <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
   </div>

   {% for post in posts %}
     <div class="">
        <div class="post">

            <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>

           <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">Comments: {{ post.approved_comments.count }}</a>
             <img src=" {{ post.img }} " width="200px" alt="images">
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <p>published: {{ post.published_date }}</p>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

form template used for getting input from user
django forms are used here..
`post_edit.html`

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{%block content%}
<h2>New post</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: add your form code snippet

Comment: You are uploading image in /image directory.